# Excel Convert Column/Row to Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking at converting an excel either via Macro or VBA with the following structure

```
1 | X  | X    | X    | X    | X
2 | Y | Y    |       
3 | Y | Y    |  
4 | X  | X    | X    | X    | X
5 | Y | Y    |       
6 | Y | Y    |
```

I need to change it to the following format

```
1 | X  | X    | X    | X    | Y | Y | Y | Y |
2 | X  | X    | X    | X    | Y | Y | Y | Y |
```

Would need to loop down the excel file and do it for multiple columns/rows.

Any suggestions how i would do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format is exactly as shown in your example and will never change, and is located in Sheet 1 starting in cell A1:

```
Sub doFormatData()
Dim shtIn As Worksheet
Dim shtOut As Worksheet
Dim rIn As Long
Dim rOut As Long
Dim c As Long

Set shtIn = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set shtOut = ActiveSheet
rIn = 1
rOut = 1

Do
    For c = 1 To 4
        shtOut.Cells(rOut, c).Value = shtIn.Cells(rIn, c).Value
    Next c
    For c = 5 To 6
        shtOut.Cells(rOut, c).Value = shtIn.Cells(rIn + 1, c - 4).Value
    Next c
    For c = 7 To 8
        shtOut.Cells(rOut, c).Value = shtIn.Cells(rIn + 2, c - 6).Value
    Next c

    rIn = rIn + 3
    rOut = rOut + 1
Loop Until shtIn.Cells(rIn, 1).Value = ""
End Sub
```

Run it from any empty sheet other than Sheet1.  First cell with data will be A1.

Comment: No, it's worse than that .... I completely missed the fact that the original dataset contained 5 `X` values.

Comment: Ayup.  People sometimes get itchy when I ask them to write out their specs instead of randomly dropping my my desk and telling me.  This is why.